# asp.net invalid postback for button onclick inside repeater footer

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given the following page (latest update).

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master/superuser.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="permissions_default" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server"></asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="Server">
  <h1>Permissions Management</h1>
<div class="row">
      <div class="span9">
        <form runat="server">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>CRM User Permissions</legend>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptUserPermissions" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptUserPermissions_ItemCommand">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table class="table table-striped autowidth">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>User</th>
                                    <th>Program</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                    </HeaderTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.user_name") %></td>
                            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.program_name") %></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="cmd_Delete" CommandArgument="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id") %>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddUser" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddProgram" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Add New" runat="server" CommandName="cmd_Submit"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="span1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
  </div>
</asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContent" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

How can I handle the button onclick events for btnSubmit and btnDelete in the repeater footer without throwing an invalid postback or callback exception?

UPDATE: Inputting the databinder.evals on the delete btn with command argument now throws out a parse erorr message that reads as follows:

```
Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to use the itemcommand event that gets triggered from a button push in the item template.  that passes in the context of the row that you can work with from there.

You can see an example here:

http://nazimakul.com/article/repeater-itemcommand-event-in-asp-net_1049

Comment: what about the submit button that is in the footer template? that is not considered to be an item row is it?

Comment: I believe the footer template can be a button like you have it. (sorry, I missed that part).  Here is an answer that seems to show it working.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897141/handling-control-events-from-repeater-footer

Comment: I've tried following the article in your answer, and in the answer from the other stackoverflow question you linked to. Both of which are still throwing invalid postback exceptions on my end. Will update my question with the latest code snippets.

Comment: Aha! found the error, essentially in the code behind I was updating those drop down lists. a quick check of if (!Page.IsPostBack) {} in the page_load prevented the error. And now Peter's answer is working out beautifully!

Comment: maybe put single quotes around 'DateItem.id'? or maybe just Eval('id')